# How to Get Specific key array in php without any loop

Tags: php

I have one multi dimentional array, the problem is I want the array values of specific key. I already tried current() and end() of array which is not useful to me. So please suggest me appropriate solution to find array values of specific key without using any loop. My Demo array is

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [EntityType] => Array
                (
                    [Id] => 1
                    [Code] => SUP/13-14/10001
                    [Name] => Supplier
                    [DisplayName] => Supplier
                    [ModuleIdentifier] => 1
                    [IsAdd] => 
                    [IsEdit] => 1
                    [IsDelete] => 1
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [EntityType] => Array
                (
                    [Id] => 2
                    [Code] => Emp/13-14-10002
                    [Name] => Employee
                    [DisplayName] => Employee
                    [ModuleIdentifier] => 1
                    [IsAdd] => 
                    [IsEdit] => 
                    [IsDelete] => 
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [EntityType] => Array
                (
                    [Id] => 3
                    [Code] => CUS/13-14/10003
                    [Name] => Customer
                    [DisplayName] => Customer
                    [ModuleIdentifier] => 1
                    [IsAdd] => 1
                    [IsEdit] => 
                    [IsDelete] => 
                )

        )

)
```

I want array having name Customer. So how to get these array...
Thanks !

Comment: What do you mean 'specific key' ? From where it is derived?

Comment: I have an answer to this maybe a simple and precise one. But, not using loop? Then how are you gonna traverse your array with finite elements to check if the **name** is equal to **Customer**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `array_filter` in conjunction with `array_map`:

```
function findElem($array, $val) {
    $result = array_map(
        function ($v) { return $v['EntityType']; },
        array_filter($array, function ($v) use($val) { return $v['EntityType']['Name'] == $val; })
    );
    return count($result)? $result[0] : false;
}

print_r(findElem($array, 'Customer'));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access n'th element of your array just try with:

```
$array[n]
```

Where `n` is an integer value, so:

```
$array[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access your array data like this: `$array[0]["EntityType"]["ID"]`.

Answer (score 0):

This line will get you all values of the key "Name" assuming your source array is named `$arr` if that's what you wanted:

```
$names = array_map( function($item) { return $item["EntityType"]["Name"]; } , $arr );
```